# If the set $A\cap\{x:|x|\geq\epsilon\}$ is finite for all $\epsilon>0$ then the set $A$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let us consider the complex plane $\mathbb C$ and $A\subset \mathbb C.$ Prove that if the set $A\cap\{x:|x|\geq\epsilon\}$ is finite for all $\epsilon>0$ then the set $A$ is countable.
**My Attempt**: By the given condition, we have the set $\displaystyle A\cap\left\{x:|x|\geq\frac{1}n\right\}$ is finite for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Now notice that,
$$A-\{0\}= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(A\cap\left\{x:|x|\geq\frac{1}n\right\}\right).$$
It follows that A is countable, as the countable union of finite sets is countable
Is my proof is correct or did I make some mistake? Please let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I suppose you would need to justify that equality. It's not correct in general.

Comment: RHS does not contain the origin.

Comment: @drhab Sir, I think adding the origin (a single point if required) does not violet the countability. So, without loss of generality we can assume $0 \notin A$, I think.

Comment: @abcdmath Indeed it doesn't, but the equality you mention is not valid in general. You can change the LHS into $A-\{0\}$ and then things are fine.

Comment: @drhab Thank you sir for your help.

Comment: Yes, because if $0\notin A$ then $A=A-\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Seems fine to me.

My only remark is that this sentence is poorly written / imprecise:

> This follows that A is countable, since union of countable finite
> sets.

I think you mean, "It follows that $A$ is countable, as the countable union of finite sets is countable".

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected it.